# Which Apple device to get to program a iOS mobile app with Trigger.io?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I want to make an iOS app but I don't have a Mac or any device with iOS. I read I can make an iOS app on Windows and Linux with Trigger.io. The app I want to make is rather simple.
What I would need is a device with iOS to test. Which devices should I get?
I was thinking on getting an Iphone 4 and Ipad 2 as they are cheap. What do you think? Will I be able to successfully build an app if I only test in those 2 devices?

Answer (score 0):

Those would be good devices to test on. You'd be missing out on an iPad with a Retina display, which would mean you'd be guessing somewhat at the appearance of icons and launch images on those screens, but the most important thing is covering the phone and tablet form factors.